# SIP is purging DYLD libraries added by SQLAnywhere17. Need these libraries to develop in flask

Tags: terminal, high-sierra, python, sip

I develop in Python 3.6 and [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). I'm currently working with a SQLAnywhere database and have installed the Python package sqlanydb. I have also installed the SQLAnywhere17 driver for Mac OSX.

Up until earlier this week I was developing normally, until I decided to update my Mac from Yosemite to High Sierra. I was unaware of SIP at the time, and so I may have made a premature decision in upgrading.

Since I've upgraded I've been unable to develop as normal because when sourcing the SQLAnywhere17 files, it adds a path to the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. However, when I run my flask application in flask's development server with

```
export FLASK_APP=modules
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
flask run
```

It purges all of the SQLAnywhere 17 dyld files that were added to my environment, and I get a `could not load dbcapi` error.

I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to disable SIP because I understand that the purpose of the protection is important. I would just like to be able to disable it for running my flask application.

My Python 3.6 files and site-packages are located in `/usr/local`. From this [article](https://apple.lib.utah.edu/automatic-disabling-sip-with-el-capitan-upgrade/) I learned I can see which files are being protected by SIP with `ls -alO`. However, when I run this command on `/usr/local` and all the directories within, and it seems that none of the files are being protected. The `/usr/local` directory itself has `sunlink` where the `protected` would be on SIP protected files. I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: How do you know that SIP is to blame? You should try disabling it at least temporarily as a test. /usr/local is indeed specifically excluded from SIP.

Comment: Yeah, good point. Let me try that and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry, for the late response. I just disabled SIP and ran my flask application using the method above. I did not encounter the error, and my flask app was able to run fine. Therefore, SIP seems to be causing this error. So then I wonder if Flask's default development server is using binaries that aren't located in `/usr/local`.

Comment: Seems that way! I'm not actually familiar with Flask, so I can't provide an actual answer. You could try disabling only the part of SIP you need (experiment to see what works): https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17452